# Cell Size and Morphology of Microalgae under Wastewater

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, morphology, algae

Hypothetical situation ahead, I am just curious whether the cell size and cell morphology of microalgae changes when it is under the influence of wastewater. For instance, mixing the microalgae culture with wastewater. If if does happens, what potential reasons are the causes of such changes?

Comment: Welcome Kris. This is very lacking in detail at present. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [ask] section of the help centre, then you can [edit] to add details such as: 1) Specifically what you mean by wastewater and in what concentration. 2) What microalgae are you referring to and what's its natural environment. 3) To show your own research into the question as per our requirements (see the [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) section for details).